# Excel: count number of unique/distinct row in range with condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet with:

- in Col A: week numbers
- in Col B: dates (timesheet entries)

I need to know the number of days worked for each week. So I need the number of unique date entries per week number.

I found formulas (both array as non-array) that handle this for a fixed range but I want to have the results in another column (per week number).

The result of the example dataset below would be (the colon is just for clarity):

```
14: 2 
15: 3 
17: 6 
20: 2 
21: 3
```

If this is the source data:

```
14: 4/04/2012
14: 4/04/2012
15: 10/04/2012
15: 10/04/2012
15: 11/04/2012
17: 26/04/2012
17: 26/04/2012
17: 26/04/2012
17: 26/04/2012
17: 27/04/2012
17: 27/04/2012
20: 14/05/2012
20: 14/05/2012
21: 23/05/2012
21: 23/05/2012
21: 25/05/2012
```

Comment: Do you want a formula to pull the distinct week numbers or are you going to create the list of week numbers independently? For instance, by doing a copy and remove duplicates.

Comment: What does it mean when the same date appears more than once?

Comment: @WalterMitty The data represents timesheet entries for a specific task/milestone. So when a week has the same date more than once, that means that there were 2 timesheet entries for that date.

Comment: @nutsch, no, I already have a seperate list of week numbers.

Comment: in that case, the countif answer below might be the easiest, unless you want the flexibility of a pivot table.

Answer (score 3):

to count the number of entries, use `=countif(A:B,D1)` assuming your week number is in cell D1, and your list of entries is in columns A and B.

Another option is to create a pivot table, with the week numbers as row labels and the count of entries as data. This will give a good summary that can be updated quickly.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do entirely with formulas. It needs a little indirect addressing and one (but for clarity I'll make it two) separate working columns along the original data, and three extra columns in the results table:

I'll assume, that the actual data starts in row 3 to allow for some headers. I'll use `;` for argument separation, which is not default for US locale. *I will not assume, that dates are sorted*. With this assumption the solution would be simpler.

1. Cell H2 (How many rows in input): `=COUNT(A3:A1048576)`
2. Cell C3 (dynamic look-up range): nothing
3. Cells C4:C1000: `=ADDRESS(ROW(A$3);COLUMN(A$3)) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW(A3);COLUMN(A3))`
4. Cell D3 (is unique): `TRUE`
5. Cell D4:D1000: `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(C4);A4)=0`
6. Cell E3 (nr of unique entry): `1`
7. Cell E4:E1000: `=IF(D4;E3+1;E3)`
8. Cell I2 (How many unique found): `=OFFSET(E3;H2-1;0)`
9. Cell J2 (Week days range): `=ADDRESS(ROW(A3);COLUMN(A3);4) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW(A3)-1+$H$2;COLUMN(A3);4)`
10. Cell K2 (Nr of unique weekday range): `=ADDRESS(ROW(E3);COLUMN(E3);4) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW(E3)-1+$H$2;COLUMN(E3);4)`
11. Cell H5 (counter): `1`
12. Cell H6:H100 `=H5+1`
13. Cell I5:I100 (position): `=MATCH(H5;INDIRECT($K$2);0)`
14. Cell J5:J100 (Week day): `=OFFSET($A$3;I5-1;0)`
15. Cell K5:K100 (Count): `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT($J$2);J5)`

The end result is in the range K5:K100.

Please note, that although I work with indirect formulas, the solution will work if you  insert a column anywhere, or delete column F:F of G:G. You can also move cells, as long as you keep columns with data together.

It is important to keep everything in one worksheet. If you insist to move table H4:K100 into another worksheet, you should modify the addresses in cells J2 and K2 to include the worksheet name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A Pivot Table might be easyest

[image: Example]